# flash object in google chrome doesn't work

Tags: html, google-chrome

when I try to add flash object to html page, flash doesn't work in chrome but works in FF: this is my code of flash:

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="50" height="50" src="images/mhe_logo.swf"/>
```

I read that google chrome not support so I replaced it with but still flash not shown ???

Comment: Use object element for flash

Comment: I used object element but it doesn't work also ...

Comment: Can you share a plunker?